# Query multiple collections and sort on output

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I want to create an activity feed and I have multiple collections.  So I have a `Posts` and `Likes` collection and I want to get all the values from both of these collections and sort them by date and return them.  Is there a way to query multiple collections without joining them in MongoDb?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to make a permanent database change, you could use the [Mongodb aggregate method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).
   However, you can also use this:

```
//This is what your final, sorted array of blog post objects will be
var blogPosts = [];
//Search posts collection
db.posts.find({}, function(err, docs){
   //Sort by how long ago post was made
   posts = docs.sort(function(a,b){return a.timeAgo - b.timeAgo});
   for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
      //Add blog post to final array
      blogPosts.push({post:posts[i], likes:0});
   };
}.exec(function(err){
   //Once executed, find likes
   db.likes.find({}, function(err, likes){
      for(var i = 0; i < likes.length; i++){
         var index = blogPosts.findIndexOf(function(post){
            //Find where in the array the postname associated with the like (I assume this is in your DB) is the name of a post
            return post.name == likes[i].post;
         });
         //Add to final array
         blogPosts[index].likes +=1
      };
   });
});
```

If you can, though, I would recommend having each blog post document have the number of likes, rather than storing posts and likes in separate collections. It will make things a lot easier.
What you have for each db document (I presume):

```
like: {
   by: username,
   post: blogpostname
}
post: {
   by: username,
   name: postname,
   timeAgo: date,
}
```

...Or something along those lines.
Instead, this is more effective:

```
post: {
   by: username,
   timeAgo: date,
   name: postname,
   likes: amountoflikes
}
```